# how to get ontouch of cube different faces?

Tags: opengl, cube, ontouch, face

I am making a cube using OpenGL.where I have a rotating 3d cube.All the six faces of the cube have different images.I am not getting a click of different faces of the cube.

example:-cube is rotating while rotating cube if I click on cube then how to get which image is clicked from all the 6 image.

Comment: You need to search for ray-box or ray-triangle intersection testing.  There is an alternative called "pick render", where you do an off-screen render of the scene using a different colour for each side, then fetch the current pixel under the mouse.  Testing its colour gives you the face that was hit.

Comment: @Robinson thanks for your feedback.  provide me any link for the ray-box or ray-triangle intersections.

Comment: @Robinson I used ray-box intersection.but I am getting only whole cube click.but I need to get separate click for each image and identify which image is click out of 6 images.

Comment: Then once you've determined the ray/box intersection worked, you then need to do ray-triangle intersections, testing each face.

Comment: @Robinson thanks for feedback.Provide links or code which I refereed and know how to testing each face and get specific image click of cube.

Comment: You can google ray-triangle intersection, or google "picking" and "pick render".  There are lots of pages out there.  Otherwise it's not a trivial problem for which I can "provide code".